# (How) Can a Rogue use the Use Magic Device feature to cast spells from Spell Scrolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, rogue

[Thief rogues](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Thief) get the [Use Magic Device](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#UseMagicDevice-367) feature at 13th level, which lets them ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items.

[*Spell scrolls*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) are an unintelligible cipher if the spell isn't on your class's spell list. If using a *spell scroll* to cast a spell higher than you're normally capable of, you need to make an ability check using your spellcasting ability against a DC equal to 10 + spell level.

Since the Thief rogue ignores all class and level requirements on the use of magic items, does this mean they may use *spell scrolls* without an ability check regardless of their level (essentially allowing them to be able to fake being a high-level caster for any class as the situation warrants)?

Or does the ability just let them attempt to use the scroll, but because the spell's not on their spell list (because they don't have a spell list), they need to make the ability check? If so, what ability would they use to make the spellcasting ability check?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### This has been addressed in the latest Sage Advice.

Thank you, @V2Blast

[Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=6)

> **Does the Thief’s Use Magic Device feature allow them to use spell scrolls?**
>
> Yes. The intent is that a Thief can use spell scrolls with Use Magic
> Device.

DMG page 141 is also of some help here (Casting Spells):

The ability check is still required to cast from the scroll but, as a Rogue has no spell-casting ability score, their's is always treated as zero when casting spells from magic items. It would stand to reason that a check would be in order to cast the spell from a scroll as well, the only issue is that it is just a d20 roll for them.

> If you don't have a spellcasting ability—perhaps you're a rogue with
> the Use Magic Device feature—your spellcasting ability modifier is +0
> for the item...

It does go on to say that your proficiency bonus (PB) does apply but this is specifically called out as an ability check so your PB does not apply to those. If it were a Wand or Staff, is what I believe the PB is intended to use.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131681/discussion-on-answer-by-slagmoth-how-can-a-rogue-use-the-use-magic-device-feat).

Answer (score 4):

## A Thief can use spell scrolls

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=6) directly addresses this issue, so if you (or your DM, if you are a player) follow the official rulings, then they can use spell scrolls.

> **Does the Thief’s Use Magic Device feature allow them to use spell scrolls?**
>
> Yes. The intent is that a Thief can use spell scrolls with Use Magic
> Device.

That just leaves the question of whether they have to make an ability check.

### By a strict reading of RAW, the Thief doesn't need to make an ability check

> Spell Scroll (DMG 200)
>
> A spell scroll bears the words of a single spell, written in a mystical
> cipher. If the spell is on your class's spell list, you can read the
> scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components.
> Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible. [snip spell casting instructions]

The above describes 2 scenarios:

1. The spell is on your class's spell list, so you can read the scroll and cast it without providing any material components.
2. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

A strict reading of those two options means that for a thief, the scroll is unintelligible.

The description of spell scrolls continues:

> If the spell is on your class's spell list but of a higher level than
> you can normally cast, ... [snip rules for making the check]

Strictly reading of RAW, since the spell is **not** on the rogue's class spell list, then this paragraph does **not** apply, and so no ability check is required.

#### Are there any requirements or other checks a thief has to make?

That still doesn't completely answer the question of **how** they use the spell scroll. For that, we have to look at the description of the ability in question:

> Use Magic Device (PHB 97)
>
> By 13th level, you have learned enough about
> the workings of magic that you can improvise the use of items even
> when they are not intended for you. You ignore all class, race, and
> level requirements on the use of magic items.

The Roguish archetype feature says that it says you **improvise the use of items**, and defines no conditions or checks on how to make it work. It simply lists out what you are allowed to ignore.

This led to this question in the first place, as what it says you can ignore doesn't directly apply to the spell scroll magic item description, but the official ruling clarifies that and doesn't lay out any additional conditions or requirements.

So, by strict reading of RAW (both rules as written and rulings as written), **no ability check is required, nor any other requirement**. The Thief simply can cast a spell from the unintelligible scroll.

#### Flavor

For an explanation of how it is possible to use an unintelligible scroll, you can just assume the Thief has watched enough magic users and memorized the words to any scrolls they found, much like Elan would be [assumed to have learned from Vaarsuvius in The Order of the Stick](https://oots.fandom.com/wiki/Multiclass_Struggles), if he choose to multiclass.

> Belkar: What about you? Throwing good levels after bad with another
> bard level?
>
> Elan: Maybe. I was also considering taking a level of
> wizard, though.
>
> Belkar: Wizard? Really? I didn't know you've been studying
> wizardry.
>
> Elan: I haven't been. But if I multiclass to wizard, it's retroactively
> assumed that I've been looking over Vaarsuvius' shoulder this whole
> time and taking notes about magic.
>
> Belkar: But you haven't been.
>
> Elan: But it's assumed that I
> have been. Get it?
>
> Belkar: Nice.

Or, you or your DM can flavor it however they would like.

### A DM could reasonably call for a skill check

Now, while a strict RAW reading doesn't require any check, it does seem intended that unless your character can normally cast the spell that some type of check needs to be made. Otherwise, you get into a situation where a level 13 Thief Rogue can cast a level 8 or 9 spell scroll, whereas an equal leveled full caster needs to make a skill check.

While there could be some legitimate flavor reason for that to be the case, a reasonable DM could also see that situation and decide that a Thief should have to make an ability check, just like a character that has the spell on their spell list, but isn't of a high enough level.

#### Making an ability check to cast a spell from a scroll

> Magic Items: Activating an item: Spells (DMG 141)
>
> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. [snip]
>
> A magic item, such as certain staffs, may require you to use your own
> spellcasting ability when you cast a spell from the item. [snip] If
> you don't have a spellcasting ability -- perhaps you're a rogue with
> the Use Magic Device feature -- your spellcasting ability modifier is
> +0 for the item, and your proficiency bonus does apply.

This passage directly refers to the Thief feature we are looking at, so provides rules if a DM decides to apply the ability check requirement to the Thief trying to use the spell scroll.

This now opens the question of whether the proficiency bonus applies to an ability check, instead of just to cases where the spellcasting ability bonus is required (like when making an attack roll with the spell).

So, what does it mean for someone to be proficient?

> 2. Choose a class (PHB 11)
>
> Your proficiencies define many of the things your character can do
> particularly well, from using certain weapons to tell a convincing
> lie.

The passage from DMG 141 about the Use Magic Device feature explicitly says that the proficiency bonus applies to making spellcasting ability checks for the Thief when using a magic item, which means that passage is saying that a Thief can use a magic item particularly well.

This means that the proficiency bonus should apply to the ability check to attempt to use the scroll. To argue otherwise is to say that a Thief **both cannot use** a spell scroll particularly well, **and can use** it particularly well if they succeed in casting a spell from a scroll that uses an attack roll. That's seems like a bit of a contradiction.

#### Reliable Talent makes most spell scroll attempts succeed

If a DM gets pushback from their Thief player that requiring an ability check makes it hard to make good use of spell scrolls, the DM should point out that the Thief also has the Reliable Talent class feature by the time they get Use Magic Device.

> Reliable Talent (PHB 96)
>
> By 11th level, you have refined your chosen skills until they approach
> perfection. Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your
> proficiency bonus, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a 10.

As the DC is 10 plus the spell level, and that by level 13 a Rogue cannot roll less than a 15 on a check that allows adding their proficiency bonus, then the Thief will always succeed on spell scrolls up to level 5.

## Summary

By strict RAW (both rules and rulings) a Thief can use spell scrolls, and there is nothing that requires a Thief to make an ability check.

A DM could reasonably require a skill check, and if so, the Thief can use its proficiency bonus as the only value it adds to the roll and keep in mind Reliable Talent applies.

Comment: I love how you specified your use of RAW is (Rules as written and Rulings as written). I was about to comment that strictly by RAW, the sage advice compendium wouldn't be included, but you already covered that argument.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that rules as written and rulings as written should be used together though. The reason a ruling needed to be made was because of how ambiguous RAW was on the subject. You set the ruling as a foundation point then used the ambiguity of the written rules that are already established as insufficient to support your argument. It isn't necessarily fallacious, but it borders fallacy if not.

Comment: @Dezvul That's why I included a lengthy section on how a DM could rule otherwise. Given the fact that a ruling had to be made in the first place, it is highly unlikely any additional rules could be used to support things one way or the other. In short, they just didn't really think about it when originally writing the rules, in terms of how Use Magic Device and Spells Scrolls would interact.

Comment: Great points, and I think your last comment supports the argument you made in the thread very well.

Comment: Another thing that could be pointed out, though this is taking it to a RAI standpoint different from the stance your argument takes, is that the only 2 possible level requirements magic items have are the spell level requirement for casting scrolls without an ability check, and the level requirement to make the Holy Avenger's aura extend to 30 ft. It would be strange to include the ability to ignore level requirements in feature's wording if there were no level requirements on the use of magic items to begin with. As far as I can tell that was meant for spell scrolls.

Comment: Honestly I've thoroughly verified this last year in trying to answer the same question regarding my artificer's magic savant feature.

Comment: @Dezvul  I find it more likely that they were just future proofing future magic items that may have had a level restriction, or maybe it was just something they didn't update after removing any level restrictions during the initial design phase. Either way it smells too much of developer intent to go down that line of reasoning.

Comment: Regarding your point:

"To argue otherwise is to say that a Thief both *cannot* use a spell scroll particularly well, and *can* use it particularly well if they succeed in casting a spell from a scroll that uses an attack roll. That's seems like a bit of a contradiction."

...isn't that true for regular spellcasters as well?  They do the ability check to see if they can cast a high level attack spell without a proficiency bonus, but then when they attack they get the proficiency bonus?

I could be misunderstanding something.