# If a Thief Rogue casts True Polymorph (Object into Creature), does the creature move on both of their turns from the Thief's Reflexes feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rogue

The Thief Rogue's Thief's Reflexes feature states:

> When you reach 17th level, you have become adept at laying ambushes and quickly escaping danger. **You can take two turns during the first round of any combat**. You take your first turn at your normal initiative and your second turn at your initiative minus 10. You can't use this feature when you are surprised.

The *true polymorph* spell states:

> [...] **Object into Creature**. You can turn an object into any kind of creature, as long as the creature's size is no larger than the object's size and the creature's challenge rating is 9 or lower. The creature is friendly to you and your companions. **It acts on each of your turns**. You decide what action it takes and how it moves. The GM has the creature's statistics and resolves all of its actions and movement.

What happens if the Thief casts *true polymorph* on an object and turns it into a creature? Does the created creature get an additional turn when the Rogue does?

---

Note: At least one way a Thief Rogue could cast *true polymorph* is through feats or multiclassing and using a spell scroll.

Comment: I'd like to point out a Thief at this level would already have access to the Use Magic Device feature, so they could definitely use a Scroll of True Polymorph without needing to multiclass, so this is definitely a situation that could occur.

Comment: It specifies that the scroll's spell has to be on your class' spell list, which exactly the kind of thing included in "You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items." A class' spell list as a requirement would fall under a class requirement.

Comment: Related to the question of whether Thief rogues can use scrolls: [(How) Can a Rogue use Use Magic Device to cast spells from Scrolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89098/how-can-a-rogue-use-use-magic-device-to-cast-spells-from-scrolls)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

Strictly going by the wording, a level 17 Thief gains an additional turn during the first round, not just acts once at a certain initiative count. Because this is an actual turn, a creature that was an object *true polymorph*ed by the Thief would be able to act on this turn.