# Who is able to cast a spell from a spell scroll in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Back in AD&D, a spell scroll was created by basically casting a spell onto a specially prepared scroll. The next person to read said scroll was able to cast the spell exactly as the original creator.

I don't think that's how it works in 5e. In fact, I thought I'd read somewhere that only a member of a spell casting class that's *able to use the spell inscribed on a spell scroll* is able to use that scroll. But I can't for the life of me find where this is written!!

So, **who is able to cast a spell from a spell scroll?**

Answer (score 4):

## All Spellcasters (with limitations) and possibly Thief Rogue

It is written in [Spell Scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) description

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

While you can't cast spells from other class lists it still provides versatility, as you can cast spells not known or prepared at given time. You can even cast spells you normally wouldn't be able to until higher levels:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully.

### Depends on DM if Thief Rogue can use spell scrolls

Per [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/10/14/thief-spell-scroll-and-use-magic-device/) rules-as-written Thief won't be able to use Spell Scrolls, yet at the same time it provides official ruling that they can. See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89098) for more details and history.